# Why am I getting "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,*,*', but only one is allowed"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, nginx, http-headers

Locally, my Angular 1.x web app has no problem communicating with a RESTful API I have running on my machine. However, when I launch the API and web app into production, I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api-domain-name-removed/api/common/protected/locations?l=1000. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,*,*', but only one is allowed. Origin 'https://client-domain-name-removed' is therefore not allowed access.

I also see this OPTIONS request failure:

[image]

However, when I use Postman, I am able to make a request against the production API without problems:

[image]

Any ideas why the request is failing from the web app?

Please note that in production, the API is running with nginx reverse proxying to an Express app, and the web app is running inside a Docker container. Also note that this same error occurs in both Chrome (v55) and Firefox (v47).

Comment: It works in Postman because Postman is not a browser and does not implement cross origin security.

Comment: Note: There are a LOT of [Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27+header+contains+multiple+values+%27%2C%2C*%27%2C+but+only+one+is+allowed.&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS515US515&oq=The+%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27+header+contains+multiple+values+%27%2C%2C*%27%2C+but+only+one+is+allowed.&aqs=chrome..69i57.735j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that discuss this exact error.  Many of them probably contain your answer.

Comment: Postman is a Chrome app which I ran via Chrome, so isn't it still within the browser?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have been searching for days, and nothing has helped.

Comment: What about this from the Google search: https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/issues/408?  It looks like the response from the OPTIONS request is supposed to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to only the specific origin that is being requested so the requesting browser knows you are approving that specific origin.

Comment: Hm, I would think * should work, though this is something to try. The question in my mind is, why is the header value set to `*,*,*`?

Comment: For the OPTIONS request, I don't think `*` will work.  I think the browser is looking to see that the server specifically approved a specific origin for the conditions that generated the OPTIONS request and it does that by returning that specific origin only.

Comment: In [6.2 of the CORS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests), it says this: **If the resource supports credentials add a single Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, with the value of the Origin header as value, and add a single Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header with the case-sensitive string "true" as value.  The string "*" cannot be used for a resource that supports credentials.**  Are you using credentials?

Comment: Nope, I searched the code extensively for `withCredentials`, and it's not present anywhere.

Comment: Well something is triggering the browser to not accept the wildcard from your OPTIONS request.  The specs are hard to read in this regard so you will probably have to try things (like what was previously suggested) until you figure out what makes it work.   `*,*,*` does not look correct to me.